# Не могу зарегистрировать приложение в google cloud platform

Tags: unity3d, google-play, oauth, oauth2, google-oauth2

Пытался зарегистрировать приложение в Googlt Cloud Platform
Просят ввести домашний сайт и ссылку на политику конфиденциальности
т.к у меня нет собственного сайта, я ввел в окошrо домашнего сайта мой тг канал, а политику конфиденциальности забросил на гугл диск

И у меня возникла проблема показанная на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В обязательном порядке требуется и то, и другое. Причем нужен домен в собственности. И это все необходимо будет поддерживать в рабочем состоянии, а изменения потребуют новой процедуры верификации. ¿А вам точно нужен Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: Здравствуйте да, я пытаюсь в свою игру добавить сервисы google play

Comment: @Ilya, для Google play console нужна, ёпрст